# Plugging external components into a managed VF page

Tags: visualforce

In my managed VF page how can I leave room for external components to be plugged in from client orgs? The key question for me here is, how do I pass variables to the placeholder so that the external component sees them.

Imagine my managed page shows Car Details. This page has a standard layout except for one area that is custom for each client. Once this page is packaged up and installed in a client org I want to be able to customize the aforementioned area. I also want this area to be aware of certain variables in the main page (e.g. Car Model, Brand, etc).

I know VF components can be plugged into pages and I can also pass parameters, but I don't think I can use them as external components (outside the package). On the other hand we have compositions that I can define dynamically on the client side (I think) but I cannot pass parameters to